# Redux handling new items and ids

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have my normalized store with lists and id mappings:

```
{
  "byId": {
    "images": {
      "10984": {"id": "10984", "src": "/img.png"}
    }
  },
  "myImages": [
    "10948"
  ]
}
```

Now I want to create a new image, and add it to the list. The problem is that I don't have an id for it until I send it to the server. So I could generate a random id

```
      "tempid19048": {"id": "tempid19048", src: "/img.png"}
```

```
  "myImages": [
    "10948",
    "tempid19048"
  ]
```

And then I save it to the server and get an id back I dispatch an action. I may have `tempid19048` used in multiple parts of the state.

What's a sane way to update everything with the new id? Am I approaching this all wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "in multiple parts of the state"?

Comment: e.g. the image id is in the list of images, and also in each album's list of images. So if I handled updating the id manually I'd have to do it in several reducers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make IDs in `"myImage"` as key-value pair.

```
"myImages": {
   "10948": "10948",
   "tempid19048": "tempid19048"
}
```

Now where ever you want to use you can use as

```
myImages["tempid19048"]
```

This will give you its current value as `"tempid19048"`.
And if you need to change this tempId you need to change only the value, and key remains same.

```
"myImages": {
   "10948": "10948",
   "tempid19048": "newServerID"
}
```

Hence, irrespective of number of places you are using `tempID` now you need to update in only one place.

Comment: Clever solution, I'll try implementing this, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because Redux is really a client-side state manager, generally you just want to mirror the global state and thats it. As you know, unlike Flux/GraphQL, there isn't any functionality for caching, optimistic updates etc. My gut tells me building this would be difficult without compromising the pure simplicity that Redux is built on.

That said, I found [redux-optimistic](https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/redux-optimist) that mimicks Flux's optimistic updates for Redux. I've not used it, but it looks nice enough.

But with even with *that* said, I'd still highlight the simple solution of designing-out any need for temp ids / optimistic updates etc:

1. make a request to create the image on the server
2. show a spinner
3. on success message from the server, add the new image with the new `id` to the global state

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think about it as optimistic updates, but that makes sense. The library looks interesting. I really avoid changing the UX when I run into technical problems, though.

Comment: I don't really see why redux shouldn't be suitable to act as a cache for optimistic updates. Just because redux itself is simplistic it doesn't mean we can't create more complicated features with it. Optimistic updates are an "improvement" to the naive design of showing a spinner and wait for the update to succeed. I don't understand what "designing-out" in that context should mean. If the payload is properly validated on the client side it is to be expected that any CRUD operations just succeed in 99.9% of cases. Optimistic updates can improve the perceived responsiveness in that case.